# Modifying text using awk

Tags: linux, text, replace, sed, awk

I am trying to modify text files using awk. There are three columns and I want to delete part of the text in the first column:

```
range=chr1      20802865        20802871        
range=chr1      23866528        23866534
```

to

```
chr1      20802865        20802871        
chr1      23866528        23866534
```

How can I do this?

I've tried `awk '{ substr("range=chr*", 7) }'` and `awk '{sub(/[^[:space:]]*\\/, "")}1'` but it deletes all the contents of the file.

Comment: The answers below describe better approaches, but to be explicit: the problem with your current `awk` commands is that you never print anything. In `awk`, if you specify an address with no commands, the default command is to print the whole line; but since you *are* specifying commands (by using `{ ... }`), it won't actually print anything unless you explicitly tell it to (by calling `print`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the field separator as `=` and print the second field:

```
# With awk                                                                     
$ awk -F= '{print $2}' file
chr1      20802865        20802871        
chr1      23866528        23866534

# Or with cut
$ cut -d= -f2 file                  
chr1      20802865        20802871        
chr1      23866528        23866534

# How about grep
$ grep -Po '(?<==).*' file
chr1      20802865        20802871        
chr1      23866528        23866534

# Temp file needed
$ cut -d= -f2 file > tmp; mv tmp file
```

Both `awk`, `cut` and `grep` require temporary files if you want to store the changes back into `file`, a better solution would be to use `sed`:

```
 sed -i 's/range=//' file
```

This substitutes `range=` with nothing and the `-i` means the changes are done in-place so no need to handle the temporary files stuff as `sed` does it for you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using tabs instead of spaces as delimiters in your file, so:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[=\t]"; OFS="\t"} {print $2, $3, $4}' input_file
```

or

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[=\t]"; OFS="\t"} {$1=""; gsub("\t\t", "\t"); print}' input_file
```

Comment: deleting fields in awk is awkward. Another approach to remove field 1: `for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) $(i-1)=$i; NF--`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to use `awk`, you can use `sed`, which I find a bit simpler. Hopefully you are familiar with regex operators, like `^` and `.`.

```
$ cat awkens
range=chr1      20802865        20802871
range=chr1      23866528        23866534
$ sed 's/^range=//' awkens
chr1      20802865        20802871
chr1      23866528        23866534
```